# Bypassing Client Side Validations to check server side validations

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have read in many books and even my opinion is client side validations are not reliable to use. That is why I always prefer using server side validations along with client side validations. Hereby, I want to know whether there is any method using which I can bypass client side validations manually so that I can check if my server side validations are working correctly. I am using JSF with Facelets as a view technology.

Comment: Manually? Just disable JavaScript in browser? Not sure if I understand your concrete problem as this is a way too obvious answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many libraries and tools. 
Here I provide two solutions:

### 1) curl command if you are using linux:

```
curl --data "year=1905&month=7"  http://yoursite.com/page.php
```

### 2) Python

```
import urllib2
import urllib

urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler()))

the_url = "http://jira-host/jira/secure/CreateWorklog.jspa"

random_user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)'

'HTTP POST fields
values = {'inline'  : 'true',
    'decorator' : 'dialog',
    'worklogId' : '',
    'id'    : '1027231',
    'timeLogged'    : '1d',
    'startDate' : fdate,
    'adjustEstimate'    : 'auto',
    'comment'   : '',
    'commentLevel': ''}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)

req = urllib2.Request(the_url, data, {
    'Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': random_user_agent,
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Referer':  'http://jira/jira/browse/TICK-216',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (until now) some possibilites to write your test for your managed beans using Java:

- [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/). It's a framework to test Java EE components.
- [JSFUnit](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit), a framework that helps you write unit tests for your JSF managed beans.
- Write your unit tests using [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) that will send requests to your page. Personally, I don't recommend this because you should do a lot of work specially to understand the parameters to send in your request to the page (yes, I know you can check the HTTP traffic using Firebug or Chrome console, but it's still not a good idea).

Comment: Thank you BalusC and Luiggi Mendoza.